# Get user IP Address website hosted in Virtual Machine

Tags: php, ip-address, virtualbox

I have my website hosted in my own server using Ubuntu and VirutalBox. I need to get user location depending on IP address. I know that I can get user IP address on client side using JS. I am trying to get user address in server using PHP, but I always get the same IP address. How can Iconfigure VirtualBox, to get user IP in server side?

Comment: From command line (Not administration) (VM - must be turn off): `VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "name_machine" --nataliasmode1 proxyonly`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**On the VM:**

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will work as long as the virtual machine is on the same subnet as the host machine with the internet connection (i.e: on Virtualbox this is called "Bridged").

If you have a "Nat"ed (or similar) connection from the virtual machine to the internet, then *all* incoming HTTP requests will be from the host machine's IP!

**On your local subnet:**

If your end-users can't directly access the "host" machine, and you've "forwarded" ports to your internal "host" machine, then you'll simply be removing one level of NAT (above) and be left with another (your router).

Comment: My virtual machine is in Ubuntu, my host is in Windows and I map the apche, ssh and mysql ports. In this case is it bridged?

Comment: Nothing to do with the "mapping" of ports, nor with Windows on the host machine. The *Virtualbox* VM configuration's Ethernet device must be "Bridged" (rather than "Nat" -- the default I think).

Comment: But! If you're saying that you're also performing NAT on your router to forward apache/ssh/mysql ports to your Windows host machine, then that will *also* cause you to lose the remote address (you'll get the router's IP address).

Comment: Yes, I am getting my router IP address, is there any way to get the IP address?Or should I get the IP address in the client side?

Comment: You *can't* get it if your router is doing simple DNAT. You'll likely need to configure a DMZ on your router, and run a reverse proxy on the "host" machine.